# No file main.bll

Tags: vscode

Unsure what the cause of this error is - just want to get LaTeX working on VSCODE.
https://pastebin.com/GGPFW2V8 <- Contains the output produced in the terminal when trying to build the project.
Please help, I would like to be able to work on this offline on VSCode.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  That log isn't of much use, I'm afraid.  It seems to show that LaTeX is running, but your document has errors.  Can you please paste the contents of the `out/main.log` file (and preferrably your LaTeX source as well)?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Hi! Sorry I haven't provided much helpful content. I'm happy to share the main.log but the actual source content is my final year project for university... I'm a bit concerned with it remaining online and then in-turn getting plagiarism for leaking own content? Probably overly cautious but can't be too safe.
https://pastebin.com/FvB41s1m - main.log
I have 10+ Files btw...

Comment: No need to paste the full document with actual content here (people don't like it when you do that). What helps is a small compilable example that shows the problem. Anyway, the log already points to the errors: 1) on line 23 of `literature.tex` there is `\includegraphics{}`: remove it; 2) on line 77 of `methodology.tex` there is `corners_o_corners_p`, which is a syntax error (maybe you want `\verb|corners_o_corners_p|`, by the looks of it); 3) on line 5 of `reflection.tex` there is a `\newline`: remove it; and 4) on line 127 of `main.tex` there is something called `keywords` which is invalid.

Comment: Unfortunately no changes using that - I'll stick to Overleaf for now. Just thought I'd try and find a way of working offline too! Cheers for the help

Comment: Well, do what suits you best. I must say it is improbable that after fixing the errors your document still doesn't work, as those were the only ones in the log.  Also maybe this vscode editor you are using is obscuring some part of the process. I'd suggest you try running `pdflatex main.tex` from the command line and see what that does, should you still want to try offline.